# Call to a member function query() on a non-object in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, object, mysqli

I have a slight problem with converting from mysql to mysqli. It consists of this error being displayed: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Here is config.php:

```
$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($db->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Error: ' . $db->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

and here is the function in statistics.php:

```
 public function getTotalServerCount() {
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM controlpanel.server';
   $total = $db->query($sql);
   echo $total;
 }
```

Please mind that this function is contained within the class called statistics.

I understand that the original code was done in a rather procedural way and I'm trying to convert it over to object oriented way but I was unable to find a solution as of yet.

Comment: Are you sure you included config file? try `var_dump($db)` in `statistics.php`.

Comment: `$db` scope is not accessible in the function. You need to pass that object in the function where you want to use that.

Comment: `$db` is not available in the scope of your `getTotalServerCount()` function

Comment: Tips: 1) Enable full error reporting (including notices) 2) Read the usage examples in the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$db` is undefined in this function scope, if `$db` is a property of that class this would do

```
$total = $this->db->query($sql);
```

alternatively you can pass it as a parameter:

```
public function getTotalServerCount($db) {
  //...
```